# Storm ORM vs PyORMish for web apps

Tags: python, orm, storm-orm

I am currently using PyORMish for powering Flask powered web apps, but since it's so new the support isn't quite there yet. I don't have any real issues other than the documentation.

On the surface they both appear to fill similar roles, but since Storm is so much larger I can only assume that it provides more features. I haven't found a good comparison of features between the two.

Has anyone here used both Storm or PyORMish? And if so, which did you find to work better with web applications?

Comment: I've been using Storm a bit. I like it a lot, but it's definitely a "work in progress". For example, it doesn't generate table SQL automatically for you, the user manual is mostly incomplete, and the syntax for some tasks (e.g. joins) is cumbersome. OTOH, some of the syntax is really nice, such as querying, paging result sets, working with models, etc. My main incentive for choosing Storm was that it doesn't have a model base class: your models can inherit `object` if you like. I'm convinced that this is the best possible design for an ORM in a high-level language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I'm the author of PyORMish (as you already know) I'll try to keep this answer as unbiased as possible.

`<opinion>`
I have used Storm in the past, but I felt it was a little too heavy for my projects. I believe that relationships are best handled by the relational database -- I don't want my ORM running multiple selects without my knowledge. It should join when I tell it to. 
`</opinion>`

Storm

- **LGPL** license
- Supports MySQL, SQLite, **Oracle**, and Postgres
- Creates database schema for you
- First release in **2007**
- Determines relationships based on **relationship classes** (Reference)
- **Full mapping**: Understands datatypes of fields
- May or may not join depending on schema

PyORMish

- **BSD** license
- Supports MySQL, SQLite, and Postgres
- Creates getters and setters for you
- First release in **2013**
- Determine relationships based on **joins**
- **Minimal mapping**: Has no knowledge of field datatypes
- Specify when to join

As for web apps, it's currently performing well with about 8,000 page turns/day at the [PyORMish website](http://pyormish.nullism.com) with 0 crashes or dropped connections as of the 1st of April. I did not notice any major concerns when running Apache benchmarks with 10k hits/minute sustained. The same is true for Storm, though. I think the argument could be made that both are production ready.

All in all, this comes down to a matter of preference.

If you're **comfortable with SQL** and creating your own schema then I'd say stick with **PyORMish**.

If you'd rather **focus on Python** and not touch SQL, you'll be more comfortable with **Storm**.

**Edit**: I'd also like to comment on the lack of documentation. I've added the most commonly requested information, and suggestions are welcome. If you're curious about some aspect of PyORMish that isn't documented then please let me know. I'll do my best to get it in the system. Please submit documentation requests via: [GitHub - Issues](https://github.com/webgovernor/pyormish/issues). Thanks!

Also, thanks for giving PyORMish a chance!

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Great summary. I have a few ideas for improving the docs. I think I will stick with what I'm doing for a little while longer.